# Stop form from open when no records

Tags: forms

I have a data entry form that when it closes opens another form for further updating the just newly entered data. However, at times no further update is necessary. How can I suppress the 2nd form from opening when there is no need for further update? Presently the form opens even when there are no recordsets present. (need a similar Event like for the report "On No Data")

Comment: Your question is not clear, please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Have a bit field such as a checkbox with default set to true open second form.  Uncheck it to avoid the system from opening the next form.  You will need to handle this in your code and check if that check box is checked or not.

Of course we will need more details such as why you are currently opening this second form...in addition, cant you check if any changes were made and if they were then open that second form else dont?  Also what lang ?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about what you're working on, I'd say you would have to modify the process that shuts down the first form to check if the second form is needed.  In .NET, for example, you could add code to the OnClosing event for a WinForm to check.  If it's needed, open it as normal, if not then don't.

Answer (score 0):

Subject: Tool Kits. Tool Kits consist of 1 or more tools. If tools already exist, no need for 2nd form to pop up. If tools are new, I need to fill in one of the 3 fields in the drop down listing. I like the idea of adding code to the OnClosing event, but do not understand what you mean by WinForm.